# AsposePDF for .Net Get existing watermarks

Tags: c#, .net, watermark, aspose.pdf

Hi I am using ApsosePDF for .Net version 17.3.0.0. I have already successfully added watermarks to pdf files using Aspose and everything works fine but I am not able to get the existing watermark object from those pdf files. Below is my sample code:

```
   public bool CheckForWatermark(Stream inputStream)
    {
        var pdfDocument = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(inputStream);
        foreach (Page page in pdfDocument.Pages)
        {
            var hasWatermark = false;
            foreach (Artifact artifact in page.Artifacts)
            {
                hasWatermark = artifact.Subtype == Artifact.ArtifactSubtype.Watermark;
            }
            if (!hasWatermark) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here **page.Artifacts** always returns zero count.I have raised a [question](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/showthread.aspx?PostID=838812&Subj=getting-existing-watermarks-does-not-work#838812) in their support forum also. Frustating that such a documented and common code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are adding watermark in the PDF correctly. You can also add ImageStamp in the PDF files by setting their opacity, which also look like watermark. Whereas when talking about watermark, check following code snippet to add it and retrieve it later.

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document();
System.Drawing.Image img = new Bitmap(dataDir + "your-image.jpg");
Watermark wm = new Watermark(img, new Rectangle(50, 100, 100, 200));
pdfDocument.Pages.Add().Watermark = wm;
pdfDocument.Save(dataDir + "output.pdf");
pdfDocument = new Document(dataDir + "output.pdf");
foreach (Artifact artifact in pdfDocument.Pages[1].Artifacts)
{
 Console.WriteLine(artifact.Subtype + " " + artifact.Text + " " + artifact.Rectangle);
}
```

I have checked above code snippet. It is working fine.

*PS: I work as support developer at Aspose.*